# The 'glory details' or 'gory details'

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-request

Are people saying the '**glory** details' or '**gory** details'?

I thought it is the '**gory** details', but I [found many examples saying the '**glory** details' from here](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4339) as well.

What's the correct one?
Or should I ask, What's the correct context to say them?

Comment: Take a look at your source: "Eggcorn Forum". An [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) is the substitution of an incorrect word or phrase that sounds like the original (and makes a certain amount of sense, unlike a malapropism which is outright nonsense). Those examples you found are there to *illustrate* that the eggcorn "glory details" exists, not that it's correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct phrase is ***gory details***, as defined [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+gory+details).

The "glory details" is likely in incorrect permutation of "gory details" originating from well-meaning people who weren't familiar with the word "gory," which is less common than the word "glory." (For evidence, see this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gory%2Cglory&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglory%3B%2Cc0).) This type of inadvertant substitution is a form of [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism).

Unfortunately, Ngrams provides little usage data for "gory details" and absolutely no data for "glory details," so while that supports my answer in general, there's not really enough data on "gory details" to be worth inserting that link here.

Comment: +1 The well-worn expression is *the gory details*. Some people mixed up *glory* with *gory* but it is so few that I have never run into it until now.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nonnal's answer that the common phrase is "the gory details".  Based on the question's ("phrase-usage" and "phrase-meaning") tags and the questions' final sentence, I think it worthwhile to also point out some more details.

The phrase "gory details" is in reference to the idea that some people prefer a simplistic summary, like "he got clobbered on the head", while other people would prefer a detailed summary, describing each blow to the head and the damage caused by each blow.  People may prefer a simplistic summary just because they want a brief overview, or because they wish to censor information, so that they don't need to hear details that they may deem to be unpleasant.  As long as they don't hear the details, their mind doesn't start contemplating unpleasant images, and they may wish to avoid that unpleasant experience if it truly is just unnecessary.

However, the phrase may often be used to describe things entirely unrelated to gore.  It is simply a common (or, at least "somewhat common") phrase.  For example, when discussing money matters, does a person describe each and every purchase, and dwell on the pain of every unnecessary expense, or do they just summarize by saying "the credit card bill".  Perhaps less commonly, the phrase doesn't necessarily need to even apply to something bad.  Maybe the only "pain" is the unpleasantness of unnecessarily taking up a lot of time to hear (or read) many details, instead of just getting a nice brief summary.  On the other hand, investigators or other people may want to sift through the "gory details" because they want access to more specific information.

As a native speaker, like NES's comment, I haven't heard of "the glory details", and it has no special meaning to me.  If I heard that, I would have just assumed that somebody was referring to some sort of specific information about honor.  I won't provide any "correct context" for that phrase, because it does sound like the phrase is unintentionally being used incorrectly, so there isn't a reason to do so.